# C# Mocking Framework that supports optional parameters and .Net 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, c#-4.0, mocking

Is there a mocking framework that exists for C# that supports .Net 4.0 and C# completely.  Specifically, I'm looking for it to support optional parameters.

Comment: I was actually able to find [NSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.com/) and it did what I need.

Comment: You should post that as an answer to your question and accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was actually able to find [NSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.com/) and it did what I need.

Comment: NSubstitute is nice, but no Silverlight support yet (03.2012).

Comment: Can't mock methods that require multi-dimensional arrays either http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912368/two-dimensional-object-array-return-type-nsubstitute

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get Moq to handle this by writing an extension method that accepted a method name and a dictionary of the parameter names and values that you *did* want to specify and the extension method creates calls to It.IsAny() for all the parameters that you didn't specify:

http://d4nt.com/handling-method-parameter-default-values-using-moq/

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure MOQ does - http://code.google.com/p/moq/

http://code.google.com/p/moq/issues/detail?id=221 - optional param support in .NET 4.0

Comment: I tried that, but I get an `System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.` exception, when the method is called without specifying the specific parameter.

Comment: Hm...I'm not sure then. I've never actually done this, I just thought it was supported.

Comment: It works for me, I just had to make sure my .Returns line had the correct definition also (INCLUDE the optional parameter, or no parameters).  So `.Returns(() => someReturnValue);` or `.Returns((int requiredVar, bool optionalVar) => someReturnValue);`.  And the .Setup needs them both as well obviously.

Comment: If you get TargetParameterCountException, check your Returns has the correct number of parameters

Comment: @MarkS., have a look on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9704789/79485 As CaffGeek and Hainesy said, it's about the .Returns parameter.