# Chaining methods with Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm attempting to mock and setup chained methods using Moq.

Here is the method I am trying to mock:

```
TeamMember teamMember = _unitOfWork
    .TeamMembers
    .Query()
    .ToList()
    .Where(t => t.AssociationCode.ToString() == code 
        && Crypto.EncryptStringAES(t.Id.ToString(), sharedSecret) == hash)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

and here is where I attempt to mock it:

```
var unitOfWorkMock = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
var iQueryableMock = new Mock<IQueryable<TeamMember>>();
var iToListMock = new Mock<List<TeamMember>>();
var whereMock = new Mock<IList<TeamMember>>();
var singleMock = new Mock<IEnumerable<TeamMember>>();

unitOfWorkMock
    .Setup(u => u.TeamMembers
        .Query())
        .Returns(iQueryableMock.Object);

iQueryableMock
    .Setup(i => i.ToList())
        .Returns(iToListMock.Object); //This line throws the error

whereMock
    .Setup(w =>
            w.Where(It.IsAny<Func<TeamMember, bool>>()))
        .Returns(singleMock.Object);

singleMock
    .Setup(s =>
            s.SingleOrDefault())
        .Returns(new TeamMember()
        {
            Email = "Test@TeamMember.com"
        });
```

When I run this test it gives me this error:

> Expression references a method that does not belong to the mocked object: `i => i.ToList<TeamMember>()`

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24719039/moq-chaining-expressions-results-in-parameter-count-mismatch) already and have tried to do something similar, but I must be missing something.

I am new to this, so if anyone can help me out it will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method chain mocking looks fine, but your problem is that [`ToList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342261.aspx) is an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx), which [Moq cannot mock](https://stackoverflow.com/q/562129/1698557).