# Two dimensional object array return type - NSubstitute

Tags: c#, .net, tdd, nunit, nsubstitute

I get a cast exception

**System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type 'System.Object[,]'.
at Castle.Proxies.ITestProxy.Get2DArray()
at Scratch.TestFixture.Get2DArray() in TestTest.cs: line 17**

from from the below:

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestFixture
{
    [Test]
    public void Get2DArray()
    {
        Substitute.For<ITest>().Get2DArray().Returns(new object[1,1]);
    }
}

public interface ITest
{
    object[,] Get2DArray();
}
```

can anyone throw any light on this? I'm thinking it's a [NSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.com/) bug?

Comment: Which version of NSubstitute are you using?

Comment: I'm away from my workstation right now so can't check, but I installed via NuGet this afternoon if that helps.

Comment: @MylesMcDonnell: MS claims the SRE bug fixed in .NET 4.

Comment: I tested this against .net 4.0 version of NSubstitute, it still fails. Perhaps NSubstitute for 4.0, is linking to a version of Castle which links to 3.5. BTW, @leppie, do you have a link to that claim?

Comment: @payo: That is what they said on the connect site. Sorry dont have the link handy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NSubstitute depends on Castle, which depends on Reflection.Emit, so they blame Reflection.Emit.

http://issues.castleproject.org/issue/DYNPROXY-154

For a workaround to your problem, looks like you cannot use multidimensional arrays. Note that your exception actually occurs on `Get2DArray()`, not `Returns`.

Please note that I, personally, am working on a mocking framework that does NOT use Reflection.Emit (nor Castle for that matter) It's going to take a few weeks before even an Alpha is ready, but it is quite a powerful tool. There are many scenarios Castle fails that I don't (my site will list these). If you are interested, please follow http://smug.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit late, but could help someone who encounters this issue and comes across this question.

We found a way around this limitation by having your Interface return `Array` instead of `object[,]`.

There is an implicit conversion, so the code inside your implementation of the interface should be able to remain the same.